# eclipse auto complete before finishing the full name of a method

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am using eclipse for Java ee. One thing I noticed is in the computer in my office, eclipse auto complete is working even though I didn't finish writing the full name of the method.

For example: as soon as I write

```
  getSer
```

It suggests me the

```
   getServletContex
```

However at home the suggestion only appear when I am done with the method name and enter "."

At the office I am using Helios and at home Juno.

Anyone knows how to make the other eclipse to auto complete before I finish the name of the method?

Comment: What is your question ? Moreover : if you are using juno or Helios then your eclipse version are different.

Comment: My question is how to make the other eclipse to auto complete before I finish the method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE only suggests these auto-complete sometimes. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to call it yourself.

Comment: Anyway it does it automatically?

Comment: sometimes it will do it automatically, but when you use backspace or something like that, it might not work those times. `CLTR+space` always works.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences>java>Editor>Content Assist and configure your settings.